# British Military Service: Regiments

Tags: military-records, united-kingdom, world-war-1

I am researching a person and on the WW1 records, it says that he was in the Royal Engineers and the Northamptonshire regiment as a second lieutenant. Is this possible, or must he have changed places.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you think the issue might be? (Hint - it will be first one then the other :-) )

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE! Can you clarify what documents you are looking at and how you accessed them?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what information you have and where you found it.  It's okay to ask for help when analyzing a document, but we can give more precise answers if you say what records you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he must have transferred or been transferred perhaps after his unit was merged or demobbed. We'd need more information to give you a clear answer.

If you have the service records(if they still exist), It should say what units he served in.